Django constraints: unique together and accept one and only one value
I'm trying to implement a constraint for the following model:
class Consumption(models.Model):
    simcard = models.ForeignKey(SimCard, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField()
    duration_billed = models.FloatField(null=True)
    volume_billed = models.FloatField(null=True)
    sms_billed = models.FloatField(null=True)

I would like to constraint the user to save one and only one value for duration_billed, volume_billed, sms_billed for a given simcard and start_date.
I have the following Meta class:
class Meta:
    constraints = [
                UniqueConstraint(
                    fields=['simcard', 'start_date', 'duration_billed'],
                    name='unique_simcard_and_start_date_and_duration_billed'
                ),
                UniqueConstraint(
                    fields=['simcard', 'start_date', 'volume_billed'],
                    name='unique_simcard_and_start_date_and_volume_billed'
                ),
                UniqueConstraint(
                    fields=['simcard', 'start_date', 'sms_billed'],
                    name='unique_simcard_and_start_date_and_sms_billed'
                ),
            ]

The problem I face with my constraints in that the DB accept several duration_billed, volume_billed, sms_billed for a given simcard and start_date.
The result I try to achieve is if a duration_billed exists for a given simcard and start_date, the user should not be able to import a new duration_billed (even if the value is different from the one stored in DB) for the same simcard and start_date. Same goal for volume_billed and sms_billed.
I hope my issue is clear. Any help or advice would be much appreciated 
Many thanks in advance

It is a DateTimeField, are you sure that the time is exactly the same? Not only the data, but the time needs to match completely.

@willeM_VanOnsem Thanks for your comment. Yes the time should match completely.

I think only UniqueConstraint(fields=['simcard', 'start_date'], name='unique_simcard_and_start_date') is required. This will ensure that for a given simcard and start_date, there will not be multiple entries. Is that what you're trying to achieve?

@anupsabraham not exactly. In this scenario, if a save a duration_billed for a given start_date and simcard, it won't be possible to save a volume_billed for the same simcard and the same start_date.

You can, you can update the volume_billed in the same object, right? Do you have to add a new row just for that?

@anupsabraham thank you for your input, I'm going to check the files that we should import and see if an update is possible instead of a new row. Thanks again for taking the time to help, much appreciated
